# Workaround to bridge a *generic* protocol to Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

Let's say that we have the following Objective-C API:

```
- (id)foo:(Protocol *)proto;
```

Which is imported into Swift as:

```
func foo(_ proto: Protocol) -> Any
```

Yep, it's one of those things that gives us a proxy object. These tend to be annoying to use in Swift, so let's say we want to make a wrapper around this thing to make it a bit friendlier. First we define a couple of Objective-C-compatible protocols:

```
@objc protocol Super {}
@objc protocol Sub: Super {}
```

Now, we define a function that takes a protocol conforming to `Super` and passes it along to `foo()`, and then we call it with `Sub` as the parameter to see if it works:

```
func bar<P: Super>(proto: P.Type) {
    let proxy = foo(proto)

    // do whatever with the proxy
}

bar(proto: Sub.self)
```

Well, this doesn't compile. The error message given is:

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'P.Type' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
```

Here's some stuff that *does* (mostly) compile:

```
func bar<P: Super>(proto: P.Type) {
    // when called with 'Sub.self' as 'proto':

    print(type(of: proto))    // Sub.Protocol
    print(type(of: Sub.self)) // Sub.Protocol
    print(proto == Sub.self)  // true

    let proxy1 = foo(Sub.self) // compiles, runs, works
    let proxy2 = foo(proto) // error: cannot convert value of type 'P.Type' to expected argument type 'Protocol'
}
```

Okay, it's the same as `Sub.self` in almost every way except that I can't pass it to something requiring an Objective-C protocol. Hmm.

The problem is that, although the fact that `Sub` conforms to `Super` means that it must be an Objective-C protocol, the compiler isn't realizing this. Can we work around that and get it bridged manually? Well, let's take a look at `Protocol`'s interface, to see if there's anything that we can...

```
OBJC_AVAILABLE(10.0, 2.0, 9.0, 1.0, 2.0)
@interface Protocol : NSObject
@end
```

Oh. Hrm.

Well, the fact that `Protocol` is a full-fledged `NSObject` subclass suggests that this is all probably the work of my bestest favoritest feature, the magical Swift<->Objective-C bridge that performs non-trivial conversions on things without it being obvious what is going on. Well, this gives me an idea, at least; I should be able to manually invoke the bridge by casting to `AnyObject` and hopefully get at the `Protocol` object that way maybe by `as!`ing it or something. Does it work?

```
print(Sub.self as AnyObject)  // <Protocol: 0x012345678>
```

Well, that's promising. And when I try it on my generic parameter?

```
print(proto as AnyObject) // Terminated due to signal: SEGMENTATION FAULT (11)
```

Oh, come *on*.

I suspect this is probably a bug in the compiler, and I plan to test a few things to determine whether that's the case, but since the Swift sources take a geologic age to compile, I figured I'd post this here while I'm waiting. Anyone have any insight and/or workarounds on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after investigating this a bit more, I've determined that it is indeed a compiler bug, and have [filed a report on it: SR-8129](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8129). What appears to be happening is that the Swift compiler falsely assumes that `proto` will always be a metatype of a concrete `class` type, so it performs the bridging by emitting a call to `swift_getObjCClassFromMetadata`, which crashes when it encounters the protocol metatype. When `Sub.self` is explicitly cast to `AnyObject`, the compiler emits `Swift._bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC<A>(A) -> Swift.AnyObject` instead, which appears to dynamically determine the type of the object and bridge it accordingly.

With this in mind, the workaround becomes apparent: cast `proto` to `Any` first, to destroy the type information associated with the generic and force the compiler to emit `Swift._bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC<A>(A) -> Swift.AnyObject`. And indeed, this appears to work:

```
func bar<P: Super>(proto: P.Type) {
    foo(proto as Any as AnyObject as! Protocol)
}
```

Not the prettiest thing out there, but probably preferable to looking up the protocol via string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not pretty and "Swifty", exactly, but getting the Objective-C `Protocol` as appropriate for passing into `foo` can be achieved using `NSProtocolFromString` as follows:

```
let proxy2 = foo(NSProtocolFromString(String(reflecting: proto))!)
```

where `String(reflecting:)` is a useful way to get the fully qualified type name suitable for resolving via `NSProtocolFromString`.

I'd say the crash you encountered is a bug.

Comment: It works! I'd tried `Mirror(reflecting: proto).subjectType`, but that of course omits the module name which is part of the full Objective-C name of the protocol. There is one hitch in that if there's actually a custom Objective-C name specified, as in `@objc(Foo)`, `String(reflecting:)`'s output will be prepended by a `__C.` prefix which will have to be removed. Also, this seems semi-undocumented, so I'm not sure I want to rely on it in production code, but this might serve as a good temporary workaround until the crash is fixed if no one comes up with a better solution. Thanks!